# Return a name from list if meeting criteria

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of people with names, age and gender which I would like to be able to extract the names of just those meeting a criteria ( >= 18)

```
people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]
```

I have tried the below but doesn't return the three names I need (John, Rachel and Deardrie)

```
def adults(members):
    for person in people:
        if person[1] >= 18:
            return members
```

Think I am missing something obvious but can't see what it is!

Many thanks

Comment: Your method will return the entire list (or whatever `members` is) after finding the first person to meet the criteria. You need to build a list and return that. You can use list comprehension for that: `return [person[0] for person in people if person[1] >= 18]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code doesn't work because you are returning the members, which is parameter. (I don't know why you have members a parameter in the first place). You can do something like this.

```
adults = [member for member in people if member[1] >= 18]
```

or If you use it in a function:

```
def adults(people):
  return [member for member in people if member[1] >= 18]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I altered the second code slightly so it only returns names and it has worked exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I made certain changes in your program :

```
people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]
def adults():
    for person in people:
        if person[1] >= 18:
            print(person[0])
adults()
```

Or you can pass the list as an argument too

```
people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]
def adults(people):
    for person in people:
        if person[1] >= 18:
            print(person[0])
adults(people)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program return the same list you send to the function 'members' you need to store the information in some place:

```
def adults(members):
    name_older =[]
    for person in people:
        if person[1] >= 18:
            name_older.append(person[0])
    return name_older

print(adults(people))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solutions would be to loop over your members list and add the ones that fit the description to a new list

```
def adults(members):
 adult_list = []
 for person in people:
        if person[1] >= 18:
            adult_list.append(person)

 return adult_list
```